# Proposition 3.11 in Wainwright's High-Dimensional Statistics

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

I was unable to follow the proof of Proposition 3.11 in Wainwright's book [High-dimensional statistics: A non-asymptotic viewpoint](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/highdimensional-statistics/8A91ECEEC38F46DAB53E9FF8757C7A4E). If $\rho$ is a metric, $\rho(x,A)=\inf_{y\in A}\rho(x,y)$, $\epsilon\ge 0$, $P[A]\ge 1/2$, random variable $X\sim P$, and $f(x)=\min\{\rho(x,A),\epsilon\}$, the proof (which is on page 71, in Section 3.2) says that $$E[f(X)]\le (1-P(A))\epsilon\,.$$

I did not see why this is true. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Show that
$$f(x):= \min\{\rho(x, A), \epsilon\} \le (1 - \mathbf{1}_A(x)) \cdot \epsilon.$$
(Think about how $f(x)$ behaves when $x \in A$ and $x \notin A$.)